# Unable to read form input value in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am working on a search autocomplete box in Laravel

**Form Code in View**

```
<form action = "/searchresult" method = "post">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Stores, Coupons or Deals" name="mysearch" id="mysearch">
<div class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-search" type="submit">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
</button>
</div>
</form>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/search/autocomplete', ['uses' =>'SearchController@autocomplete']);
```

**JS**

```
$( "#mysearch" ).autocomplete({
source: "search/autocomplete",
minLength: 1,
autoFocus: true,
select: function(event, ui) {
window.location.href = "/deals-coupons/" + ui.item.url;
},
focus: function( event, ui ) { event.preventDefault();}
});
```

**Controller Method**

```
public function autocomplete(Request $request)
{
    $term = $request->input('mysearch');
    // $term = $request->get('mysearch');
    Log::info('Search Term:  '.$term);
    $results = array();
    $queries = DB::table('merchants')
            ->where ('merchant_name','LIKE', $term.'%')
            ->take(5)
            ->get();
    foreach ($queries as $query)
    {
        // Log::info('Query:  '.$query);
        $results[] = ['id' => $query->merchant_id, 'value' => $query->merchant_name, 'url' => $query->merchant_url_text];
    }
    return $results;
}
```

I have tried the following

```
$term = $request->get('mysearch'); 
$term = $request->input('mysearch');
```

but none of these is returning the search term I am trying to type. As you can see I am logging the search term in my laravel.log file and each time it is coming empty. Because the term is empty it is always showing top 5 results from the merchants table.

Can someone please help me understand what mistake I am doing.

Comment: what was the auto-complete library being used?

Comment: Have you tried `Input::get('mysearch')`?

Comment: Well, what does `print('<pre style="color:red;">');
print_r($request->all());
print('</pre>');`?

Answer (score 3):

You can try following

#### For Javascript

```
 $('#mysearch').autocomplete ({
        minLength : 1,
        autoFocus : true,
        source : '/search/autocomplete'
        
    });
```

#### For Server Side To Get Value

```
$term = $_GET['mysearch'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working.

On the server side, it was about using

$term = $request->input('term'); instead of $term = $request->input('mysearch');